# Vaadin: update from 23 to 24 fails to start

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

I get error:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: './target/flow-frontend/form' is not a valid version!
        at com.vaadin.flow.server.frontend.FrontendVersion.<init>(FrontendVersion.java:160) ~[flow-server-24.1.12.jar:24.1.12]
```

This happens because package.json has:

```
    "@vaadin/field-highlighter": "24.1.9",
    "@vaadin/form": "./target/flow-frontend/form",
    "@vaadin/form-layout": "24.1.9",
```

So @vaadin/form is missing, but instead it should be built.
Earlier it was:

```
    "@vaadin/field-highlighter": "23.1.0",
    "@vaadin/flow-frontend": "./target/flow-frontend",
    "@vaadin/form": "./target/flow-frontend/form",
    "@vaadin/form-layout": "23.1.1",
```

I did usual "mvn clean", deleted node_modules and target, but no help.
It seems that it does not build the flow-frontend now, there is no such folder in target.

-Harri

Comment: The "@vaadin/form" has not existed for a while, it is "@hilla/form" nowadays, but why you have this in your packake.json in a Flow project is a bit mystery to me.

Comment: 23 was working fine with this @vaadin/form, I don't know why.
I don't remember though what was the previous version, in which it was added.

Comment: Ok I got it working! Deleted package.json and package-lock-json from application root.
It seems that new Vaadin creates these in folder:
src\main\dev-bundle
I wonder why this dev-bundle is now needed... the demo application does not have it and it starts much faster.
Also demo application automatically starts in browser why my old app does not.

Comment: Added to application.properties:
vaadin.launch-browser=true